# Raspberry Pi SD Card Reader Overheat?

Tags: usb, pi-3b+, sd-card, display, mouse

We have Raspberry Pi 3B, and tried plugging it in after trying to supply power using the GPIO pins but to no response. We tried to turn it on again using the cable charger we initially used but only the red and green lights appear, no display at all. A little while and we noticed the hot sd card, it didn't smoke though. After removing the sd card (it was hard to touch it at first), we noticed there was smell coming from the sd card reader. Do we need a new sd card or a new pi?

Update: We have successfully opened the pi, but the problem is now the USB port. We tried inputting the mouse but it doesn't move at all. Is the USB port damaged? Is it the power? Is it the SD Card?
P.S. Have tried other mouse, but still doesn't work

Comment: Which pins did you feed power into? What voltage did you feed in? Try a new or spare sd card.

Comment: I have seen hot (once even almost melting) USB sticks when connected to the Pi 3 and 4, while supplying it the traditional way (via USB). Now micro SD that hot is the first time; you may consider double checking where you are supplying voltage to it, and at what voltage.

Comment: At least 2.5A 5V.

Comment: It is officially Raspberry Pi power adapter?

Comment: Sounds like you've gone off-piste and found the kind of damage that you can do when trying to go rogue. Go back to the most basic use case of the Raspberry Pi first: standard USB power; and see if it works. If you can get it working there, then you're likely not providing sufficient power through your custom route.